# Writing unit test for make handler function in Go-kit

Tags: unit-testing, go

My problem is specific to Go-kit and how to organize code within.
I'm trying to write a unit test for the following function:

```
func MakeHandler(svc Service, logger kitlog.Logger) http.Handler {
    orderHandler := kithttptransport.NewServer(
       makeOrderEndpoint(svc),
       decodeRequest,
       encodeResponse,
    )

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.Handle("/api/v1/order/", orderHandler).Methods("GET")

    return r
```

}

What would be the correct way of writing a proper unit test? I have seen examples such as the following:

```
sMock := &ServiceMock{}
h := MakeHandler(sMock, log.NewNopLogger())

r := httptest.NewRecorder()
req := httptest.NewRequest("GET", "/api/v1/order/", bytes.NewBuffer([]byte("{}")))

h.ServeHTTP(r, req)
```

And then testing the body and headers of the request. But this doesn't seem like a proper unit test, as calls other parts of the code (`orderHandler`). Is it possible to just validate what's returned from `MakeHandler()` instead of during a request?

Comment: what is returned from `MakeHandler` is a `mux`, you can test your mux using functions that let you see inside a `mux` like so https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Route.GetMethods. However, doing that restricts your test case, to your specific type of `mux`. In future if you end up using a different router, this test will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Yes, that test is in the right direction. You shouldn't try to test the
internals of the returned handler since that third party package may change in ways you didn't expect in the future.

> Is it possible to just validate what's returned from MakeHandler() instead of
>   during a request?

Not in a good way. `MakeHandler()` returns an interface and ideally you'd use
just the interface methods in your tests.

You could look at the docs of the type returned by `mux.NewRouter()` to see if
there are any fields or methods in the concrete type that can give you the
information, but that can turn out to be a pain - both for understanding the
tests (one more rarely used type to learn about) and due to how future
modifications to the `mux` package may affect your code without breaking the
tests.

> What would be the correct way of writing a proper unit test?

Your example is actually in the right direction. When testing `MakeHandler()`,
you're testing that the handler returned by it is able to handle all the paths
and calls the correct handler for each path. So you need to call the
`ServeHTTP()` method, let it do its thing and then test to see it worked
correctly. Only introspecting the handler does not guarantee correctness during
actual usage.

You may need to make actually valid requests though so you're able to understand
which handler was called based on the response body or header. That should
bring the test to a quite reasonable state. (I think you already have that)

Similarly, I'd add a basic sub test for each route that's added in the future.
Detailed handler tests can be written in separate funcs.